# error in compilation book documentclass

Tags: books, compilation-error

It is not the first time I work with the *book* documentclass. Apparently, I did not do anything different but this time I get a strange error message:
I have, of course, a master document and a series of chapters on different files. If I compile the document from the master everything goes well I I obtain a nice .pdf with all the chapter. However, if I compile from one of the chapters I often (but not always) obtain a series of errors. Not a big deal, because I can go back on the main document, compile, and everything is fixed, but it should not behave in this way and it never did in my previous books.

This is my main document:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}



\begin{document}

\author{Me}
\title{My life}
\date{January 2021}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/capitolo01}
\include{./TeX_files/capitolo2}

%la "casa"
%a scuola (Aldo Moro, Campanile boia)
%i libri

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

The chapter format is simply:

```
\chapter{Capitolo primo}
text
```

and the error messages:

```
Undefined control sequence. \chapter
Missing \begin{document}. \chapter{C
Corrupted NFSS tables. ...qualcuno: scrivo a un ipotetico "voi" ma è
Missing \begin{document}. P
Missing \begin{document}. S
Missing \begin{document}. I
Missing \begin{document}. P
Emergency stop.
Font shape `/cmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `/cmr/m/n' instead
Font shape `/cmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (9.44446pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (6.80557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.44444pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (2.77779pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (2.77779pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (2.77779pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55557pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Looks like it does not understand that the chapter is linked to the main document.

Comment: If you want to compile only one chapter you can use the \includeonly command in your main document to restrict the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

> If I compile one of the chapters...

You can't compile the chapters separately, as they don't have the document class and the rest of the preamble that make them valid latex documents.  The preamble defines the commands like `\chapter` and this is why you get the `undefined command sequence` error.

So you can't run  `pdflatex capitolo01.tex` and get a nicely formatted version of just one chapter.  If your editor offers to process the current file with latex it needs to process the whole book and not just one chapter at a time.

If you want to preview just one chapter you can create a short stub master file that has the documentclass and the rest of the preamble, but only imports a single chapter. Or you can use the `\includeonly` command to select particular chapters from the master document.  But as computers can process a complete book in a blink of an eye, there is limited benefit to this.

Comment: I understand now that I was not clear in explaining the issue: I do not mean to compile a single chapter independently. I work with TeXstudio with both main document and chapter open in two different tabs. In other books I used to  work on the chapter, then  compile and  obtain the compilation of the entire book without errors. Now, I can obtain the correct compilation if I move into the  main document and compile from there, I get errors if I compile from the chapter tab. It did not happen in the past, and it does not happen 100% of the times, occasionally the compilation is correct.

Comment: this aspect breaks my work flow: when I compile from the chapter, I just hit a button and I can see the last changes in the pdf. If I get an error I have to move to the main document tab, compile, then move to the specific point I am working on (because the end of the pdf file is shown)

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved!
I had copied the directory to a different location, and opened one chapter from the old directory. That is the reason that prevented the correct compilation of that specific chapter.